# worker-loader doesn't work properly after restart

Tags: vue.js, webpack, web-worker

I'm trying to use web with vue-cli project.

My worker is in file **user.worker.js**. When I run `vue-cli-service serve` for first time it works, but after restart webpack tries to load **user.worker.worker.js** and cant because such file doesn't exist. If I rename or move the file it works for first time but after restart fails again.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Worker from "@/user.worker";

export default {
  name: "App",
  created() {
    const inst = new Worker();
    inst.postMessage({
      path: `some data`,
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

**user.worker.js**

```
onmessage = async ({ path }) => {
  postMessage({ path });
};
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule("worker")
      .test(/\.worker\.js$/)
      .use("worker-loader")
      .loader("worker-loader")
      .end();
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "worker-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```